# Trigger to ReAssign Leads - Need Test Class

Tags: apex, leads

I created a trigger to reassign a lead if the lead owner is inactive (and the lead is updated).  However I can't figure out how to write a test class, especially with the @future clause.

```
public static Boolean assignAlreadyCalled=FALSE;

public static boolean assignAlreadyCalled(){
    return assignAlreadyCalled;
}

@future
public static void assign(List<Id> lIds){
assignAlreadyCalled = TRUE;
List<Lead> leads=[SELECT Id, OwnerID FROM Lead WHERE Id IN: lIds];



  for(lead l:leads){        
     List<User> users=[SELECT Id, isActive FROM User WHERE Id =:l.OwnerId];
      for(user u:users){
        if(u.isactive == FALSE) {
          Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
          dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule= true;
          l.setOptions(dmo);
        }
     }
  }
update(leads);
```

The test class I have so far is as follows; it fails as the assert equals... it shouldn't equal.

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class LeadAssign_Test {

@isTest public static  void TestLead() {

System.test.StartTest(); 

  Profile prof = [select Id from Profile where Name ='System Administrator'];  

  // Create a test Lead
  User use = new User(LastName = 'TestUser',
                      Alias = 'test', 
                      Email = 'test@test.com',
                      username = 'testington@testingtonpalace12345.com',
                      CommunityNickname = 'anickname',
                      ProfileID = prof.Id,
                      LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                      LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                      TimeZoneSidKey = 'GMT',
                      isActive=True,
                      EmailEncodingKey='ISO-8859-1');

  insert use;

  Lead lea = new Lead(LastName='LeadTest',
                      Company = 'TestLead',
                      Status = 'Open',
                      OwnerID = use.id, 
                      DoNotCall=False);
  insert lea;

    //try{
        use.IsActive = False;
        update use;            
    //}catch(Exception e) {
    //  System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
    //}


    //try{      
        lea.DoNotCall = True;
        update lea;            
    //}catch(Exception e) {
    //  System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
    //}



System.test.stopTest();     

//*** User ID (inactive from above) should NOT equal owner of the Lead
System.assertNotEquals(use.Id, lea.OwnerId);
}     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to requery the Lead record BEFORE the assert. E.g:

```
test.stopTest();

Lead testLead = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Lead WHERE Id : lea.Id]

//*** User ID (inactive from above) should NOT equal owner of the Lead
System.assertNotEquals(use.Id, testLead.OwnerId);
```

Also, unrelated but it is bad practice to use SeeAllData=true. I can't see how/why you using it.

Comment: I included this line in the code as you mentioned, but the final assertion still has the two IDs being equal... where they shouldn't be.  So the question is how can I confirm that the lead IS being set to the proper owner upon creation and is being reassigned... is there a way to call the method in the main class directly to fire?